# Crystalreportviewer not rendering (asp.net mvc4 razor syntax)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2010

I'm trying to create a crystal report in asp.net mvc4 (razor syntax) in visual studio 2012. I read some articles on web that there are two ways of achieving this with razor views.

1: The simple pdf rendering without the crystalreportviewer
2: create aspx page and load crystalreportviewer on that.

I'm going with the second method where I've create an aspx page and in my controller's action, I have the following code.

Controller.cs (Action)

```
if (this.HttpContext != null && this.HttpContext.Session != null)
{
     this.HttpContext.Session["ReportName"] = "AccountStatement.rpt";
     this.HttpContext.Session["rptSource"] = reportInfo;
}
// Redirecting generic report viewer page from action
Response.Redirect("~/AspForms/aspnetgeneric.aspx")
```

In codebehind of aspnetgeneric.aspx page load, I have:

```
string strReportName = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["ReportName"].ToString();
ReportDocument rd = new ReportDocument();

string strRptPath = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Reports"), strReportName);
rd.Load(strRptPath);

if (source.GetType().ToString() != "System.String")
     rd.SetDataSource(source);
CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = rd;
```

Code runs fine without any exceptions on runtime but does not show the crystalreportviewer or the report itself in the browser window. (Tested on all major browsers). I tried changing the target framework to 4.0 from 4.5 but still the same.
What may i be missing? Any clues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made it work by doing the following:

I read on [SAP Support](http://scn.sap.com/thread/3449786) that 'IIS Express is not supported as it does not allow for integration of 3rd party components' so i shifted my site to IIS7.5.

Then i copied the crystalviewer13 folder along with the aspnet_client folder to root of my website and gave full admin rights.

Lastly I had to add the javascript file (crystalreportviewers13/js/crviewer/crv.js) in aspnetgenric.aspx that brought back the crystalreportviewer.

I thought to share this if it could help somebody in future.

Answer (score 2):

Can you check is it showing any error from your browser console window. (You can go to browser console window by pressing F12).

You can try following way

Copy **aspnet_client** folder from c:\inetpub\wwwroot folder to the new website(your project's) root folder.

Comment: Hi Hasib, thanks for taking out time for a reply. I read somewhere that IIS Express (VS12) doesn't give support to the third parties components so i shifted my site to IIS7.5!! Then copied the crystalviewer13 folder along with the aspnet_client folder to root of my website and gave full rights.
Lastly I had to add the javascript file (crystalreportviewers13/js/crviewer/crv.js) in aspnetgenric.aspx that brought back the crystalreportviewer.